# Can not connect to the host itself

Tags: centos, iptables, cron, apache-httpd, curl

Well, the problem is simple. I have the site based on apache and trying to execute cron job at this site from the same server. Let's say my site http://example.com and cronjob is

```
/usr/bin/curl http://example.com/cron.php
```

It does not work, error is "curl: (7) couldn't connect to host".

Why this could happen?

P.S. The site is working fine and accessible from any other external machine/client.

Here is an output of iptables -S

```
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 2222 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
```

Ping failed: (ping example.com) - here I've used my server domain, of course:

```
134 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 136759ms
```

Comment: many reasons possible. dns, iptables...

Comment: @murphy Thank you, what I need to start from?

Comment: You can start from clarifying your situation, please.

Comment: It was a clean Centos 6.5 server. I've installed apache, php, mysql, copied the site from another server, disabled SELinux, added a rule to iptables which enables access to ports 80 and 443 from anywhere. Now the site is working and accessible from anywhere except server itself.

Comment: Use a different URL for internal traffic. Does it work then?

Comment: @FarazX Yes, working fine with http://127.0.0.1/ and http://localhost/ but it is accessing different site (I have lots of virtual hosts identified by domain name)

Comment: check name-resolution: `host example.com`

if possible, deaktivate ip-tables; ping example.com; recheck curl; check if routes are correct `ip route get <YOUR GATEWAY>`; if behind nat, check nat rules of gateway; from there check if your apache config is working

Comment: ping failed: check my initial message please

Comment: Try Creating a Custom ICMP rule (using Echo Request). In addition you can add a firewall rule that allows inbound from the elastic IP.

Comment: @farazx May you tell how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

It may be due to many reasons.

/**First of all, I gotta say this is more related to [serverfault.com](http://serverfault.com) not here*.*/

It is so ordinary not being able to access the external address of the network from within the internal network and itself since the traffic from the external address is sent back to the internal network. So it can most likely be **DNS issue**, and as I mentioned earlier in comments, you can use a different URL for your local network and for internal traffic - i.e. use split DNS.

BTW, Depending on the connection type you have, **you may not be able to access anything if the external IP is the same as the server's IP**, so be aware of your network topology and gateway configurations. I'm not a network expert, so I just can help you with system administration - that's why I recommend [serverfault.com](http://serverfault.com), not this place.

BTW, [this is something useful](https://superuser.com/questions/888014/i-suddenly-can-t-access-my-own-web-server-within-my-lan-via-the-external-wan-ip) - though it was on Windows system not Linux, network is network - which I found on SuperUser.com, I think this can help you much, and here is what **JakeGould** has said in his answer:

> My money is on some kind of NAT loopback setting on your router being
>   reset or deactivated. NAT loopback allows you to access port-forwarded
>   services—like web services on port 80—on your router’s external IP
>   address as well as the internal IP address.
>
> Is your router perhaps an ISP-supplied router/modem combo? It could be
>   that your ISP reset or upgraded the router/modem firmware and the NAT
>   loopback settings were munged in the process. Many ISPs reserve the
>   right to remotely access the router/modem the provided you with to
>   perform routing maintenance at times and something like NAT loopback
>   is a fairly non-standard setting that could be easily overlooked—or
>   ignored—during such a reset. Now I am not condoning your ISP reseting
>   your equipment without your knowledge, but just putting that out there
>   as something that might happen if you are using ISP supplied
>   equipment.
>
> I would recommend going into your router’s config to see if NAT
>   loopback options—or something similar sounding—exists and see if
>   adjusting that clears things up.

Meanwhile, due to what you said about **Ping failure**, you can add a custom ICMP rule in `iptables` since Ping operates by sending Internet Control Message Protocol (ICMP) Echo Request (Type 8) packets to the target host and waiting for an ICMP Echo Reply(Type 0), the syntax is real easy:

```
$ iptables -A INPUT -s x.x.x.x -p ICMP --icmp-type 8 -j ACCEPT

#OR if you don't know ICMP type numbers

$ iptables -A INPUT -s x.x.x.x -p ICMP --icmp-type echo-request -j ACCEPT
```

BTW, be aware that your **cron job syntax** should be something like this:

```
 # ┌───────────── min (0 - 59)
 # │ ┌────────────── hour (0 - 23)
 # │ │ ┌─────────────── day of month (1 - 31)
 # │ │ │ ┌──────────────── month (1 - 12)
 # │ │ │ │ ┌───────────────── day of week (0 - 6) (0 to 6 are Sunday to
 # │ │ │ │ │                  Saturday, or use names; 7 is also Sunday)
 # │ │ │ │ │
 # │ │ │ │ │
 # * * * * *  command to execute
```

I recommend you find the issue and find out what causes this problem by checking your network and system configurations you've made or is set, and then attempt a solution. **Avoid doing things unless you know what it is**.